# jquery/IE mousemove event triggered as tooltip fades, but mouse isn't moving

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, tooltip, fadeout, mousemove

I'm trying to get a tooltip to work so that it fades out after it is shown. My code works great except in IE8 - the mousemove event (over an image) keeps getting triggered as the tooltip fades and it creates a pulsating effect... fading in/out/in/out.

The problem has something to do with the tooltip because if I get rid of the tooltip code, the mousemove event is only called when the mouse is moved.

You can see a simplified example here:

[click to see simplified example (use IE8)](http://code.redtopia.com/examples/tooltip-test/)

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this? I can't seem to get it to proc.

Comment: Nope. Couldn't rep it under ie9 (ie8 mode). Worked as expected

Comment: You're using JQuery 1.5.2 - try upgrading to 1.6.2 as this could very well have been fixed in the source.

Comment: For googler's sake: for some reason I also get these spurious mousemove events in IE when animating a div's opacity using jquery, completely separate from the mouse, which is over a different div entirely. Storing the mouse coords to see if it's _actually_ moved, as below, did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, my idea for a fix seems to work:

```
ElementLooper.prototype = {
init: function(items, control, outer){
...
var self = this;
...
this.px = null;
this.py = null;
...
outer.mousemove(function(e) {
                  if (self.px == e.pageX && self.py == e.pageY) {
                    return;
                  }
                  self.px = e.pageX;  self.py = e.pageY;
                  self.show_control();
                });
```

Comment: I see... so you're saving the current mouse position in the mouse move event as globals and then checking to see if the position has changed before you do anything? Interesting. I wonder if this is a known bug of if it needs to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I can reproduce this in IE7 and IE8, jquery-1.6.2

I've written an image slideshow that uses fadeIn()/fadeOut() to switch between images. If the mouse cursor is over the slideshow, the img title="..." tooltip appears when an image is switched in. When the tooltip disappears (the browser fades it after a few seconds), the mousemove() handler is called.

See the front page of http://davidhoulder.com for an example which currently (24 July 2011) provokes this bug in IE7/8. If I manage to fix or workaround this I'll update this answer.

One possible fix is to save .pageX and .pageY in the .mousemove() handler and just return if the mouse really hasn't moved.